# Hive Table Export Optimization

Tags: hadoop, hive

I'm looking to optimize or reduce the number of steps in the below workflow.

I have a Hive table named say Logs.
I apply some custom udfs to obtain Transformed Logs.

I created transformed logs as a table with something like

```
CREATE TABLE transform_logs
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
AS
SELECT nonsafehash(visitorid), nonsafehash(url), action  FROM logs
```

I then do

```
./bin/hadoop dfs -cat  /user/hive/warehouse/transform_logs/\* > transform_logs.csv
```

Only to then do

```
./bin/hadoop dfs -put  transform_logs.csv /some/other/path
```

Are my last two steps equivalent to simply 'mv' ?

My end goal is to have a single csv under /some/other/path.

It seems like I should not have to write to the filesystem to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to concatenate the files into a single file, I believe the only way to do this circumventing the local FS is to use a single reducer by issuing:

```
set mapred.reduce.tasks=1
```

prior to issuing your `CREATE TABLE` query.

Then you can do a `hadoop fs -mv`.  Of course your query will be slower because of the single reducer, but it appears to be a necessary tradeoff if you require the data concatenated to a single file.